# how to check services running on ssh sessions?

Tags: server, bash, ssh, vpn

There was a VPN server, set via SSH session, on an Ubuntu 14.04 amd64. It is based on go language, so there were some environment variables required. I know these environment setting will be gone after terminating the ssh conversation, which they did. However, the VPN service somehow could last, even after I terminated the SSH session, my devices still can connect to the vpn. In new ssh session, env settings are gone, new server service could not be started unless reset those env variables. How could this previously started vpn server still running without these? And, in new ssh session, I checked `ps` and `jobs`, vpn server is not there, how to stop it? Thanks

Comment: Did you do `ps` or did you do `sudo ps aux` when checking for the process? Try the second. I'll bet you'll see it running.

Comment: Find the PID of the service process then do `cat /proc/<pid>/environ` maybe? See [Environment variables of a running process on Unix?](http://serverfault.com/questions/66363/environment-variables-of-a-running-process-on-unix)